# Textual replacement macros to wrap environment

Tags: macros, environments

I want to create simple textual replacement macros for an environment:

```
\def \myEnvStart {\begin{someEnvironment}[enormous list of arguments]}
\def \myEnvEnd {\end{someEnvironment}}
```

This doesn't work:

```
\myEnvStart
    stuff
\myEnvEnd
```

This works:

```
\myEnvStart
    stuff
\end{someEnvironment}
```

**Why?** Is it possible to make the first code snippet work somehow?

Comment: The first version works too, so I guess, it might depend on the particular `someEnvironment`

Comment: My guess is you're trying to use your macro-like setup for something like `align`, right? What is the specific use-case?

Comment: Be careful of what you want may be a side effect. \myEnvStart 
stuff
\myEnvEnd is not \begin{myEnvStart}
 stuff
\end{myEnvEnd}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this works, when you're dealing with ordinary environments that merely perform replacements of their `\begin`-`\end` counterparts. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% Just for this example

\def\myEnvStart{\begin{center}}
\def\myEnvEnd{\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\myEnvStart% \begin{center}
\lipsum[2]% Center this text.
\myEnvEnd% \end{center}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

However, "not all environments are created equal". Some are created in a special way that make them require to see their `\end{<env>}` counterpart explicitly. Here's an example of that using the `verbatim` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% Just for this example

\def\myEnvStart{\begin{verbatim}}
\def\myEnvEnd{\end{verbatim}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\myEnvStart% \begin{verbatim}
\lipsum[2]% Center this text.
\myEnvEnd% \end{verbatim}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Replacing `\myEnvStart`/`\myEnvEnd` with `\begin{verbatim}`/`\end{verbatim}`, of course, yields the desired result:

[image]

In a broader sense, some environments are written in this special way because they do more than just insert their environment start/end replacements. They may which to capture the entire environment content, perhaps to allow multiple processing of the content - [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) does this, as does the `align`-and friends environments of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

It may not necessarily be for multiple processing as [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)'s `lstlisting` requires the same treatment because of category code changes (similar to our `verbatim` example above). Category codes need to be restored at the end of the environment, and to do so correctly, some environment gobble their contents wholly before working on it.

So the answer is "Yes", it works, but only in some cases.

Of course, the next question is whether a work-around to this exists. Sure there is a work-around... but also only in some cases. For example, you may be able to get away with your macro-like interface by grabbing the "environment" content yourself before passing it on to "the real environment". Here's such a way when looking at the first example:

```
\long\def\myEnvStart#1\myEnvEnd{%
  \begin{center}
    #1
  \end{center}}
```

The macro parameter text now includes the anticipated "environment end code" `\myEnvEnd`, implying that `#1` will be the entire "environment" content. The [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) provides exactly this approach, although it requires the use of a `\begin`/`\end` pair.

You can't employ the above-suggested method with `verbatim`-like text (including `lstlisting`) as they change category codes, so again, only in some instances.